# Angular-jwplayer issue

Tags: angularjs, jwplayer

Hi I am using angular Jwplayer https://github.com/ds62987/angular-jwplayer to play HLS(live streaming).
I have the html

```
 <jwplayer player-id="{{cameradetails.id}}" camera="cameradetails"
    setup="liveStreamCtrl.options"></jwplayer>
```

And the Controller looks like

```
var cameraObject = {
image: "../../assets/images/main/live-streaming/video-default.jpg",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    androidhls: true,
    playlist: [{
        sources: [{
            //Desktop: Use RTMP protocol and played by flash.
    file: "//52.2.142.67:1935/58d385775914156fc85a2795/" + window.localStorage.getItem('token') + "/58d65451555c6d75e3b7c51f.stream"
                       }, {
    //Mobile: Use HLS protocol and played by HTML5
    file: "//52.2.142.67:1935/58d385775914156fc85a2795/" + window.localStorage.getItem('token') + "/58d65451555c6d75e3b7c51f.stream/playlist.m3u8"
                        }, ]
                    }],
                    primary: "flash"
             };
    var dahuaCameraObject = cameraObject;
    self.options[value.id] = dahuaCameraObject;
```

When I an running setup it is giving me the  following error and returns player timeout err.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#58d3ba2dfc21ab4b4dc7199f-ade55c26e70e4' is not a valid selector.
at http://localhost:8585/client/dev/assets/js/clientAccount/directives/player.js:5:12043 (anonymous) @ player.js:5 player.js:5 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element':  #58d5fa103f2bba6af0327842-85fa6e4830107' is not a valid selector. at http://localhost:8585/client/dev/assets/js/clientAccount/directives/player.js:5:12043
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePNZr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
androidhls: true,
primary: "flash"
```

I changes this to

```
  "primary": "html5",
  "hlshtml": true,
```

i.e playing the videos by html5 instead of flash is woking fine